# How to connect an EC11E rotary encoder to a microcontroller?

Tags: encoder, debounce, rotary-encoder

I'm connecting a [EC11E](https://tech.alpsalpine.com/e/products/category/encorder/sub/01/series/ec11e/) rotary encoder to a Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE. The EC11 has 5 pins: 2 for the switch, and 2 for the knob.

Connecting the encoder itself would be easy, but I'm having a hard time finding out how to add debouncing capacitors and resistors.

This is the schematic I've found to be best but I'm not sure about the numbers; some schematics use 100 nF and 1 kΩ while others use 10 nF and 10 kΩ. What difference do these numbers make to the signal?

[image: ec11 schematic]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does EC11 Incremental Encoder need hardware debouncing and VCC for encoder?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512042/does-ec11-incremental-encoder-need-hardware-debouncing-and-vcc-for-encoder)

Comment: So from my understanding, the lower the resistor resistance the better? And higher capacitance the better?

Comment: Debouncing should be done in your software. The R and C should help with ESD.

Comment: So what values should R and C be?

Comment: Not super critical. The ones in the schematic should be adequate.

Comment: What is important is the *time constant* (R*C). It needs to be long enough to filter the bounce, but short enough so the software won't miss fast user input.

Comment: Also see answers here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/632802/raspberry-pi-not-reading-rotary-encoder-accurately/632809#632809

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you pick component values for a debouncing filter?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/423688/how-do-you-pick-component-values-for-a-debouncing-filter)